# Single vs Multi Line: Different results after setting variables, and Only if parameters are passed from command

Tags: windows, batch, script, code

Why do these two sets of code-blocks give different results when everything is the same, except for the structure of the IF Statement? Interestingly, the only time the result fails is when I pass the values for the two variables from the command line. It is at that moment the Single Line command fails.

Below is a snippet of the two code-blocks:

I have narrowed it down to setting the second variable on the same line that causes it to fail.

**This fails:**

```
if "%~1" NEQ "" (set num1=%~1 & set num2=%~2)
```

**While this works:**

```
if "%~1" NEQ "" (set num1=%~1)
set num2=%~2
```

**Code:**

Must pass two numbers for the arguments to see the issue

Numbers should be valid for searching for a substring of a 10 character string.

EX. 2 and 1, 3 and -1, 0 and 5, etc.

If you don't pass numbers, and instead, set the variables manually in the batch, both code blocks work fine. As stated earlier, the issue is only when arguments are passed, and only for the single line command.

```
@ECHO off & cls
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET str=ABCDEFGH
        
::This code works!
echo This will give the correct answer
if "%~1" NEQ "" (
   set num1=%~1
   set num2=%~2
)
set ans=!str:~%num1%, %num2%!
echo Answer = %ans%

::This code fails!
echo.
echo This will NOT give the correct answer
if "%~1" NEQ "" (set num1=%~1 & set num2=%~2)

set ans=!str:~%num1%, %num2%!
echo Answer = %ans%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set num1=%~1 & set num2=%~2` isn't equivalent to the 2 commands running separately at all because there's a **trailing space** after `%~1`. That's why people always say you should use `set "var=value"` even when the commands are on separate lines because non-visible characters at the end will still go into the variable without the user noticing. `set "num1=%~1" & set "num2=%~2"` will work as expected

```
:: Works
set num1=%~1
set num2=%~2
echo [%num1%], [%num2%]

:: Doesn't work, do you see the difference between this and the above?
set num1=%~1 
set num2=%~2
echo [%num1%], [%num2%]

:: Equivalent to the above
set num1=%~1 & set num2=%~2
echo [%num1%], [%num2%]

:: Works
set "num1=%~1"    
set "num2=%~2"    works even with spaces and random strings after
echo [%num1%], [%num2%]

:: Works
set "num1=%~1" & set "num2=%~2"
echo [%num1%], [%num2%]
```

Comment: I had a hunch because the wrong answer had an extra space in it, though still learning the quirks of batch, it didn't even register with me that a space before '&' would contribute to this. I will certainty be wrapping my variables going forward!

Answer (score 0):

```bath
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cls & set "str=ABCDEFGH"
        
:: This code works!
echo;This will give the correct answer
if Not "%~1" == "" set /a "num1=%~1, num2=%~2"
set "ans=!str:~%num1%,%num2%!"
echo;Answer = %ans%
```

---

You are using numerical comparison as if it were a string comparison, merging the commands/comparisons:

- Use `if` compare between (integer) number:

```bath
if Integer NEQ Integer (command)

if 100001 neq 000001 (pause)
if 000001 neq 100000 (pause)
```

---

- Use `if` compare between strings:

```bath
if "string" == "string" (command)
if "case sensitive" == "case sensitive" (pause)

if /i "string" == "STRING" (command)
if /i "case insensitive" == "CASE InSenSiTiVe" (pause)

if Not "case sensitive" == "case sensitive" (pause)
if /i Not "case insensitive" == "CASE InSenSiTiVe" (pause)
```

---

- Define two or more numeric variables on the same line using:

```bath
set /a "NameVar=Value, NameVar=Value, NameVar=Value"
set /a "var1=INTEGER, var2=INTEGER, var3=INTEGER" 
set /a "var1=100001, var2=200001, var3=100000"
```

---